# How to access a component's child components in a guard in Angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a way to access a component's child components in a canDeactivate guard in Angular2?

```
canDeactivate(component: any, route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routeState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
...
}
```

I'm trying to save the state of specific child components, e.g. save the state of all GridComponent in a component. I would like to avoid adding @ViewChildren on every component for which I need to save the state of some of its childs componenent. I had a look at the code of Augury but it uses ng.probe and it seems to work only in production mode.